# Scatter Plot Interpretation for Temperature and Precipitation

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, scatterplot

The precipitation data points don't make a straight line along the blue regression line and most of them are present between 24.25-25.25 °C (approximately).

What does this tell me about the correlation between these two variables? Maybe a low positive correlation?

Where `AvgTMean` = `Average annual mean temperature`

`AvgPpt` = `Average annual precipitation`

Purpose:

I am looking to see `correlation` between `Average annual mean temperature` and `Average annual precipitation`.

The plot was generated using the `ggstatplot` package.

Data (`df`):

```
structure(list(year = 1980:2021, AvgTMean = c(24.2700686838937, 
23.8852956598276, 25.094446596092, 24.1561175050287, 24.157183605977, 
24.3047482638362, 24.7899738481466, 24.5756232655603, 24.5833086228592, 
24.7344695534483, 25.3094451071121, 25.2100615173707, 24.3651692293534, 
24.5423890611494, 25.2492166633908, 24.7005097837931, 24.2491591827443, 
25.0912281781322, 25.0779264303305, 24.403294248319, 24.4983991453592, 
24.4292324356466, 24.8179824927011, 24.7243948463075, 24.5086534543966, 
24.2818632071983, 24.4567195220259, 24.8402224356034, 24.6574465515086, 
24.5440715673563, 23.482670620977, 24.9979594684914, 24.5452453980747, 
24.9271462811494, 24.7443215819253, 25.8929839790805, 25.1801908261063, 
25.2079308058908, 25.0722425561207, 25.4554644289799, 25.4548979078736, 
25.0756772250287), year.1 = 1980:2021, AvgPpt = c(202.704111130864, 
114.247733460745, 126.199474853408, 141.152117838805, 116.203497094368, 
130.77896716476, 126.350886628546, 107.205512960324, 91.6244152459231, 
72.3675977029335, 107.065495697931, 138.900189676504, 114.878379703938, 
117.930669633136, 156.362504334285, 149.231959978739, 123.880574706985, 
148.447735131721, 135.237081261339, 145.989968136124, 105.967135316339, 
120.919120551475, 105.667550237949, 119.329320418424, 94.5035688452337, 
134.475944917217, 100.046199758505, 112.607532853243, 117.968374857272, 
146.639791754533, 132.227290150763, 117.147468204471, 145.947365902934, 
112.396272586057, 125.093465198045, 113.700379223659, 125.374770243706, 
163.60349436601, 130.849234933763, 155.373781692023, 224.255287296813, 
127.831766140872)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -42L
))
```

Code:

```
library(ggstatplot)

# Check correlation between AvgTMin and AvgPpt
ggscatterstats(data = df, x = AvgTMean, y = AvgPpt)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Could you provide some guidance concerning what you mean by "interpret"? What is your objective and where are you having problems?

Comment: @whuber sorry I forgot to add the plot, I am looking to see correlation between `Average annual mean temperature` and `Average annual precipitation`. Moreover, I would like to know what `the scatter plot`, `bar plots` and `statistical values` tell me about the variables.

Comment: That's a little too broad and vague to work here on CV.  Could you narrow your questions to one specific one?

Comment: @Whuber no worries, can I ask two separate questions then for the same data analysis, one for the plot elements (scatter and bar plots) and one for the statistical values?

Comment: Yes, you can.  I would suggest asking them sequentially, though: post one, see what you learn from the answers, and then consider whether you still need to post the next.

Comment: @whuber is it better now, please suggest any further edits if needed, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139175/discussion-between-ed-gravy-and-whuber).

Comment: Plotting is good. However, if you are interested in correlation, an obvious approach would be calculating a correlation coefficient (such as Pearson's or Spearman's correlation coefficient) and its confidence interval (see R function `cor.test`). Judging from the plot, the correlation appears to be rather weak, possibly even zero.