# Yearly average correlation vs Monthly average correlation

Tags: correlation

Based on this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588655/scatter-plot-interpretation-for-temperature-and-precipitation), I am seeing negligible correlation between temperature and precipitation. Since, the data points represent annual averages for 42 years, will it make sense to correlate the same variables but this with time monthly averages for the same timeseries to get better/improved correlation results (due to more data)? Or the correlation might still be poor?

Comment: Correlations can be different when data measured over shorter time periods, this is common in financial markets. E.g., zero correlation in daily returns and positive correlation in 6-monthly returns. Whether you are likely to observe it is thus a context-specific question. As cloudy days are both more-likely to be cooler and more-likely to have rain, my uninformed guess is a small negative correlation at some measurement length.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of data analysis isn't usually to try to find the strongest correlation possible, it's to answer a question about the world. In your case, these two possible tests correspond to two quite different questions: a) is there is an association between average annual temperature and total annual rainfall?, and b) is there is an association between average **monthly** temperature and total monthly rainfall? Which question are you trying to answer?

Comment: So I already did yearly average correlation (average values for each year for 42 years), and now I want to see monthly average (average monthly data for each year for a 42 a year time period (1980 - 2021)) association between these two variables. Purpose is to see whether the correlation will vary in the latter case or not because of more data. Like will I still see negligible correlation, negative or positive. Basically to see if more data is better for correlation analysis or not.

Comment: But that's not MORE data, it's DIFFERENT data, addressing a different question. More data in this case would mean annual data going further back in time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/330205)

Comment: @Eoin so based on your feedback, would it be advisable to analyze this different data to see association between these two variables?

Comment: @AdrianKeister, the question was whether a particular analysis would make sense. I've explained the circumstances under which this analysis would or would not make sense. I struggle to see how you could think this "does not provide an answer to the question".

Comment: When I write "Which question are you trying to answer?", I'm asking rhetorically, I'm not asking the OP for clarification.

Comment: @Eoin Fair enough; thank you for adding the clarification about not asking rhetorically - it was not obvious from your post that it was rhetorical. I don't know that I have the permissions to retract my review, but you can consider that done, from my perspective.